# HTTP 1.1 Transfer-Encoding:chunked opens new TCP socket each time

Tags: http, http-headers, transfer-encoding

**Protocol used**: HTTP 1.1

**Header includes** 'Transfer-Encoding: chunked'

On sending subsequent requests (same request to the same server), containing 'Transfer-Encoding: chunked', I see new TCP socket being opened for each request.

Should the same socket not be used for requests? Why is the socket being terminated each time?

**Note:** 
Requests sent using fiddler

Comment: Is it not left to Fiddler to decide whether to use a new socket or not ?

Comment: @GajananH : If the parameter 'Transfer-Encoding: chunked' is not used, fiddler is not terminating the TCP socket. Only on including this parameter, I noticed new socket being created each time.

Comment: The client side has to keep open connection. Probably it closes it and you see new connections. Or there is `Connection: close` in HTTP headers.